# Не работает hover, не могу понять в чём дело

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Не работает hover, работаю на вордпресс и создал колонку и присвоил ей класс и потом ещё в стилях самому этому классу псевдокласс.

```
.category-box {
    border: 2px solid white;
}

.category-box:hover {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Может поверх есть какой-то прозрачные элемент? Задай ему `z-index` и проверь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас фон (картинки) дочерних элементов перекрывают родительский стиль несмотря на z-index... Не спец в вёрстке, но псевдоэлементы вас спасут:

```css
.categorybox {
  position: relative;
}

.categorybox:after {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.categorybox:hover:after {
    background: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WordPress ни при чём. Скорее всего, ваш стиль элемента перекрыт другими стилями.

Кликните правой кнопкой на элементе, выберите "Просмотреть код". Откроется dev tools. В правой части надо кликнуть на `:hov` и в открывшейся панели отметить `:hover`. Ниже будут выведены стили элемента при наведении. Можно искать там, или выбрать "Computed", найти там `background-color`, раскрыть его и посмотреть, какие стили и откуда влияют на окончательное значение этого свойства.

Comment: вот сайт http://euroingridients.monotone.by

Comment: У вас в стилях нет этого вообще. Вы в какой файл этот css код поместили?

Comment: корневой шаблона style.css

Comment: Не шаблона, а темы - используйте правильную терминологию. Вот ваш css- файл `http://euroingridients.monotone.by/wp-content/themes/themetrust-weston/style.css?ver=4.9.6`, и где там `.category-box` ?

Comment: У вас в html `categorybox` и `category-box`, а в css `.categorybox` - надо повнимательнее как-то.